# is there a way to get a JSON object as input in GET type Spring REST Service?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, post, get

I don't wanna use it as a POST method as it a listing service and the JSON object helps to get the Filter parameters. Below is my code which I made to work using POST. Is there a way to do the same using GET ( Comply with REST standards in Spring-Boot?

TimeEntriesRequest is my POJO request class and TimeEntry is my bean

```
 @RequestMapping(
        method=RequestMethod.POST,
        value="/TimeEntries",
        //consumes = "application/json",
        produces = "application/json"
    )
@ResponseBody
public List<TimeEntry> getTimeEntries(@RequestBody TimeEntriesRequest timeEntriesRequest) throws RestClientException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    System.out.println("In controller");
    return timeEntriesService.getAllTimeEntries(timeEntriesRequest);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot doesn't support `@RequestBody` with the GET method, but you can try to use another annotation - @RequestParam.

```
@RequestMapping(
    method=RequestMethod.GET,
    value="/TimeEntries",
    produces = "application/json"
)
@ResponseBody
public List<TimeEntry> getTimeEntries(
   @RequestParam(value = "personDTO") String timeEntriesRequestDTO) {
   TimeEntriesRequest timeEntriesRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(timeEntriesRequestDTO, TimeEntriesRequest.class);
   //       ...
}
```

There is a [tutorial](https://lankydan.dev/2017/03/11/passing-data-transfer-objects-with-get-in-spring-boot) you can follow to implement it

P.S. I don't think this is a recommended approach, because json will be in the request url, so you need to check if there are any other approaches before use this one.